# Strange JSON.Stringify() Behaviour

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, web

I'm not sure if this is strange behaviour or I am doing something wrong bur check this out -

```
{
 "query": {
     "bool" : {
        "should" : {
                    "match" : { "pty_forename" : "nathan" }
                   },
        "should" : {
                    "match" : { "pty_surname" : "smith" }
                   }
              }
         }
}
```

Copy and paste that into [JSONLint](http://goo.gl/H5z6W) and see what happens, the exact same thing happens whenever I try to parse this with JSON.Stringify(). The actual problem is that all of what I am trying to parse doesn't successfully parse, i.e. missing -

```
"should":{
          "match" : {"pty_forename": "nathan"}
}
```

What am I doing wrong, can anyone offer some insight?

Thanks.

Comment: What seems to be the problem here? You have duplicate keys overwriting each other.

Comment: "Valid JSON", "the exact same thing happens" --- if it succeeds in both cases - congratulations.

Comment: What does jsonlint say? We don't want dependency on external resources

Comment: I don´t think you are able to have too "should" like that. Two properties with the same name and different values.

Comment: I do need two should's in there, as its for ElasticSearch.

Comment: Either change it to a list `"should": [....]` or rework your redesign.

Comment: you have two objects with the same name `should`... when you try to parse it it blows up and only keeps the last one it read with that name...

Comment: @NSmeef: I'm sure you've confused the format. Look at the format requirements once again

Answer (score 1):

If you are to have several "should" they should be in an array like this:

```
{
 "query": {
     "bool" : {
        "should" : [{
                    "match" : { "pty_forename" : "nathan" }
                   },{
                    "match" : { "pty_surname" : "smith" }
                   }]
              }
         }
}
```

or like this:

```
{
 "query": {
     "bool" : 
     [{ 
    "should" : { "match" : { "pty_forename" : "nathan" }},
    "should" : { "match" : { "pty_surname" : "smith" }}
    }]
}
}
```

All depending on the implementation you desire.
[Example from W3 Schools.](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)

Comment: How about providing an example using OP's data structure?

Comment: So you joined 2 `should` into one, but left `match`es as separate objects. Doesn't look consistent

Comment: Well, depends on what you are trying to do. This way you will "should" contains several objects that have the "match" attribute. It could work just fine depending on the implementation of which OP haven´t provided any details...

Comment: Indeed, in either way it's just guesses

Comment: One may also group on "bool" instead making that the array, containing several "should" objects by just moving the square brackets to enclose two should "objects" instead.